# C# Regex Optimization

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# application, which I'm using RegEx to run an expect from a Unix response.
I currently have this.

```
//will pick up :
//  What is your name?:
//  [root@localhost ~]#
//  [root@localhost ~]$
//  Do you want to continue [y/N]
//  Do you want to continue [Y/n]
const string Command_Prompt_Only = @"[$#]|\[.*@(.*?)\][$%#]";
const string Command_Question_Only = @".*\?:|.*\[y/N\]/g";
const string Command_Prompt_Question = Command_Question_Only + "|" + Command_Prompt_Only;
```

This works as I've tested it with [www.regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com), but I think I need some optimization as there are times, it seems to slow way down when I use Command_Prompt_Question.

```
var promptRegex = new Regex(Command_Prompt_Question);
var output = _shellStream.Expect(promptRegex, timeOut);
```

I might want to mention I'm using SSH.NET to talk to these Linux servers, but I don't think it's a SSH.NET issue because when I use Command_Prompt_Only it's fast.

Does anyone see any issues with the const string I'm using?  Is there a better way to do it?

My project is open source if you feel like you want to go play with it.
https://github.com/gavin1970/Linux-Commander

Code in question:
https://github.com/gavin1970/Linux-Commander/blob/master/Linux-Commander/common/Ssh.cs

It's call Linux Commander and I'm attempting to build a virtual linux console with Ansible support.

Comment: Have you tried using a cached (`static readonly Regex`)  with `RegexOptions.Compiled`? I note that your regex is using ECMAScript syntax `/g` which is not supported by .NET - you also aren't putting each sub-expression in a non-capturing group - is that intentional?

Comment: Wasn't aware that /g wasn't supported.  Thanks for that info.  So, are you saying by grouping it will make it faster?   ([$#])|(\[.*@(.*?)\][$%#])|(.*\?:)|(.*\[y/N\])|(.*\[Y/n\])

Comment: btw, static readonly should be used for public, where const is more for private use and would be faster for the reads.   This variable isn't something that should change, once I get it set correctly.

Comment: That is incorrect: you cannot use `const` with reference-types like `Regex`, you can only use `static readonly`. Saying "const is faster" is an oversimplification: `const` and `static readonly` have different semantics and the C# compiler will inline `const` values even across assembly boundaries (which can be a source of bugs if you don't rebuild when updating assembly dependencies).

Comment: Using `/g` in ECMAScript regex is the same as enumerating all `Match` values in the `MatchCollection` - however your code doesn't seem to evaluate the regex by itself, instead it's done by the `.Expect` method. Where is that defined and what does it do?

Comment: That .Expect is part of SSH.NET, you'll have to dig around in their code to find it. https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/ShellStream.cs#L549

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo
{
    const string Command_Prompt_Only     = @"[$#]|\[.*@(.*?)\][$%#]";
    const string Command_Question_Only   = @".*\?:|.*\[y/N\]";

    const string Command_Prompt_Question = "(?:" + Command_Question_Only + ")|(?:" + Command_Prompt_Only + ")";

    private static readonly Regex _promptRegex = new Regex( Command_Prompt_Question, RegexOptions.Compiled );

    public void Foo()
    {
        // ...

        var output = _shellStream.Expect( _promptRegex, timeOut );
    }
}
```

Comment: `/g` has no meaning in .net, it matches a literal slash followed by 'g'.

Comment: @PoulBak I left that in my answer because at the time I didn't know if the OP wanted it there or not.

Comment: You should also use non-greedy quantifiers, that will speed up.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone see any issues with the const string I'm using?

Yes too much backtracking in those patterns.

If one knows that there is at least one item, specifying a `*` (*zero or more*) can cause the parser to look over many zero type assertions. Its better to prefer the`+` (one or more) multiplier which  can shave a lot of time off of researching dead ends in backtracking.

---

This is interesting `\[.*@(.*?)\]` why not use the *negative* set (`[^ ]`) pattern instead such as this change:

`\[[^@]+@[^\]+\]`

Which says anchor off of a literal "[" and the find 1 or more items that are not a literal "@" (`[^@]+`) and then find 1 or more items that are not a literal "]" by `[^\]+`.

Comment: I have in the post above, what I'm attempting to capture.  There are many scenarios and I must pass them all in with one call to SSH.NET.   @ is part of the string I'm looking for.  [root@localhost ~]# is just one scenario.

Comment: I have taking your suggestion about * vs +.